# Is Response.Redirect available in global.asax using IIS 7 Integrated Mode?

Tags: .net, iis-7, global-asax

I'm researching an issue we're having with IIS 7 running in integrated mode.  We have several applications running in .net 3.5.  The standard way we have always caught and dealt with unhandled exceptions is to utilize the Application_Error method in Global.asax (in this case, the unhandled exception is an HttpException that is created when a request is made for an aspx page that doesn't exist).

Inside Application_Error, we use our custom error handling to log the error to the database, send an alert email, and then redirect to the specified error page.  The error logging and alert email works as expected.  The redirect does not.

I've used Fiddler to view the request/response and I'm getting an HTTP 302 to a page completely different than what is in my customErrors section.

Why doesn't Response.Redirect work in Application_Error?

Here's my code so far:

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim ex As System.Exception = Server.GetLastError
    Server.ClearError()

    If Not (TypeOf (ex) Is HttpException) Then
        //Run our internal error handling here
    Else
        Dim httpEx As HttpException = CType(ex, HttpException)
        Response.Clear()
        Response.StatusCode = httpEx.GetHttpCode()
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = True
        Server.Transfer("../Error.htm")
    End If
End Sub
```

This runs fine when I try to visit an aspx page that does not exist.  However, it doesn't work for static pages.

I've tried so many variations that this code is currently running without a customErrors or httpErrors section.

Answer (score 0):

If it is going to the IIS error page, you will need to set [TrySkipIisCustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors.aspx) to true.

Comment: I implemented this and it worked but only when I call Server.Transfer to a static page, not an aspx page.  Any ideas why?

Comment: @Chuck Can you post your Application_Error code and your <customErrors> section of your web.config?

Comment: I'll post it in the morning.  Thanks.